# Sort rows of two-dimensional array in ascending order according to sum of all positive even elements in every row C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I need to find sum of all positive even numbers in every row (which I've already done actually). And then I have to sort these rows depending on their sums

As I think, it must be done in one function (otherwise there will be no connections as I cannot use global variables). In my case it's `void print`:

```
void print(const int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > 0 && arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                //cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl << "Sum of positive even elements in the row " << i + 1 << " = " << sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int** createMalloc(int, int);
int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns);

int** createNew(int rows, int columns);
void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows);

void init(int**, int, int);
void freeMemory(int**, int);
void print(const int**, const int, const int);

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns);

void main() {
    int rowCount, colCount;
    cout << "Enter number of rows: "; cin >> rowCount;
    cout << "Enter number of columns: "; cin >> colCount;
    cout << " Array creation algorithm\n";
        start:
    cout << "Input number : \n1 for malloc\n2 for calloc\n3 for new\n";
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    switch (k) {
    case 1: {
        int** a = createMalloc(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        freeMemory(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        int** a = createCalloc(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        freeMemory(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        int** a = createNew(rowCount, colCount);
        initPrint(a, rowCount, colCount);

        deleteNew(a, rowCount);
        break;
    }
    default:cout << "Input 1, 2 or 3, please.";
        cout << endl << endl;
        goto start;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

int** createMalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)malloc(rows * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(columns * sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createCalloc(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = (int**)calloc(rows, sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*)calloc(columns, sizeof(int));
    }
    return arr;
}

int** createNew(int rows, int columns) {
    int** arr = new int* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr[i] = new int[columns];
    }
    return arr;
}

void initPrint(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    init(arr, rows, columns);
    print((const int**)arr, rows, columns);
}

void init(int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    const int Low = -2, High = 4;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Low + rand() % (High - Low + 1);
        }
    }
}

void freeMemory(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}

void deleteNew(int** arr, int rows) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}

void print(const int** arr, int rows, int columns) {
    // виведення масива на екран
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > 0 && arr[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                //cout << setw(7) << arr[i][j];
                sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            }
        }
        cout << endl << "Sum of positive even elements in the row " << i + 1 << " = " << sum;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

P.S. Two-dimensional arrays must be necessarily dynamic ones. Also, cannot do this task using `vector`. Only `malloc`, `calloc` and `new`

Comment: In case you're unaware of `std::vector`, I strongly suggest learning that first. It will make writing code much easier.

Comment: @ovvvol This declaration const int** arr does not declare a pointer to a two-dimensional array.

Comment: @ovvvol You can use the standard function std::sort to sort pointers to one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @ovvvol And if this is  a C++ program then why are you using ,malloc instead of the operator new?

Comment: Do you know how to sort an array of `int`? If you have an array of `int`, and another array of the same number of elements of another type, so that each `int` corresponds to an element of the second array, and you now how to swap elements of the first array in order to sort it, do you see how you could perform the same swaps on the second array?